# Retrieving database dump after copying from remote server

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I used command

```
pg_dump -C -h remotehost -U remoteuser db_name | psql localhost -U localuser
```

to copy database on remote server to my local machine.

Can I somehow retreive the dump obtained after the first part of the command, i.e.

```
pg_dump -C -h remotehost -U remoteuser db_name
```

is executed? Can it be stored in some temporary location?

Answer (score 2):

The first command does not store the created file anywhere, so the answer is: no, you can't retrieve that file because there is none.

If you need such a file, you can either re-run the first statement and provide a filename using the `-f` switch.

Or, if f you have not yet changed your local database,  then you can simply dump that.

Answer (score 0):

> pg_dump -C -h remotehost -U remoteuser db_name | psql localhost -U localuser

this command does a dump and pipes the result to a local session, no copy is stored.

Assuming bash (or compatible shell)
If you want to do the same but also store a copy do:

```
pg_dump -C -h remotehost -U remoteuser db_name | tee /tmp/copy-of-dump | psql localhost -U localuser
```

or you can make a dump of your local instance

```
pg_dump localhost -U localuser > /tmp/dump-of-local
```

if you want a compressed dump: `tee >( gzip > /tmp/dump-of-remote.gz )`